# union types and flexible array member

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have a question about the flexible-length arrays in C structures (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

```
typedef struct  {
    size_t N;
    int elems[];
} A_t;
```

Now the general approach is quite obvious,

```
A_t * a = malloc(sizeof(A_t) + sizeof(int) * N)
a->N = N;
....
```

Now this seems to be awkward when trying to incorporate stuff into other structs or stack-based allocation. So something like the following snipet is bound to fail for `N!=0`

```
struct {
   A_t a;
   A_t b;    /// !!!!!
   double c; /// !!!!!
};
```

Now I think it should be possible to allow for usages like this by defining another type

```
typedef struct  {
    size_t N;
    int elems[5];
} A_5_t;

struct {
   A_5_t a;
   A_5_t b;
   double c; // should work here now.
} mystruct;
```

and then use it as if it were an `A_t` structure. When calling a function `void foo(A_t * arg1);`, one would need to use something like `foo((A_t*) (&mystruct.b))`. Which -- to me -- appears to be a bit clumsy. I therefore wonder whether there is a better way to do this. I wonder whether one could employ a union type for this somehow?

I am asking this question, because the flexible-length array makes it possible to have data in one piece in the structure, therefore one can copy a struct with a single command instead of having to worry about deep and shallow copies, etc.

Comment: Your link, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html , is to a GCC extension to C90. Your example, `int elems[];`, uses a C99 (and C11) feature called “flexible array member”. You do see the difference between `[0]` and `[]`, do you not? `elems` is **not** an array of length zero in `int elems[];`. Arrays of length zero are forbidden by all C standards (which makes them a good place for an extension, but does not make them incomplete arrays).

Comment: I do see the difference between zero length and flexibel length arrays. The GNU page I linked to actually documents both. My question was about how to use the pattern of allocating struct and flexibel-array length effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out now (the solution has actually been descibed in the gnu documentation as provided above). By appending an array declaration after the struct declaration, one does create a contiguous memory range that is directly adjacent to the "empty" flexible array. Therefore `b.A.elems[i]` is referencing the same data as `b.elems_[i]`.

It is probably advisable to choose an identifier that tells you that the memory of this array is actually belonging to the structure. at least thats how I would use it then.

```
typedef struct  {
    size_t N;
    double elems[];
} A_t;
typedef struct {
    A_t a;
    double elems_[4];
} B_t;
void foo(A_t * arg1) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < arg1->N; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", arg1->elems[i]);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B_t b;
    b.a.N = 4;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i) {
        b.elems_[i] = 12.4;
    }
    foo(&b.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mult-layered question.

In this one example:

```
struct {
   A_t b;
   double c; /// fails
};
```

I would try:

```
 struct {
    double c;
    A_t  b;
 };
```

Always place the variable portion of a struct at the end.  Note, I don't use GCC, so try this, it might/maybe work.

To follow-up on a requirement given by @wirrbel, the following struct is **NOT** variable length, but it does define and provide access to a variable length array of integers.

```
typedef struct  {
    size_t N;
    int *(elems[]);  // parens to ensure a pointer to an array
} A_t;

A_t *a = malloc //etc.

a->elems = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

In this fashion several `A_t` structures can be included in a more general structure.

Comment: hi, this might be a good approach, but it fails with two members of type A_t. I have probably over-simplified my example code in that respect.

Comment: @wirrbel, have expanded on my answer given your comment.  Please re-review and if necessary provide more detail and I will respond.

Answer (score 1):

No, in general your two `struct`, `A_t` and `A_5_t`, are not interchangeable. The reason is that the version with the flexible array can have different padding in front of the `elems` field than versions with a fixed field length.

Whether or not your compiler implements a different padding or not, you can test by using the `offsetof` macro. But even if the offsets are the same for your particular compiler and platform, you'd better not rely on that if you want portable code.